# nodejs streams file system

Tags: node.js, filesystems, node-streams, node.js-fs

I have created a readstream whose default readableHighWaterMark value if 65536 and also created write stream whose default writableHighWaterMark value is 16384 and Iam sending data from readstream to writestream but when I am debugging and the writestream writable length is reaching max to 65536 but its default value was 16384 hows this possible ?

```
        console.log(readStream.readableHighWaterMark);  // default 65536 bytes
        console.log(writeStream.writableHighWaterMark); // default 16384 bytes
    
        readStream.on("data", (chunk) => {
            if (!writeStream.write(chunk)) {
    // console.log("write water mark value at full: " + writeStream.writableLength); // 65536
                readStream.pause();
            }
        });
    
        writeStream.on("drain", () => {
            readStream.resume();
        });
    
        readStream.on("end", () => {
          console.log(readStream.readableHighWaterMark);   // default 65536 bytes
          console.log(writeStream.writableHighWaterMark);  // default 16384 bytes
        });
```

Comment: `writeStream.write` accepts the chunk, even if that exceeds its highWaterMark, but it will then not accept further chunks (and warns the caller through the return value `false`). Refusing the chunk without prior warning would be unfair.